# Get the CSS files routes

Tags: php, css, symfony, assetic

I'm working on an existing project and I'd want to know the CSS files that are dumped with the command: `php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug`

Is there any way to know it? I'm getting the next output:

```
12:52:11 [file+] /home/MyServer/project/app/../web/compiled/css/b2b7f11.css
12:52:12 [file+] /home/MyServer/project/app/../web/compiled/35563da.js
```

Comment: If you turn your Assetic config like `assetic: use_controller: false` wouldn't output the real names? Haven't tried it.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure how you can get the route that is create by assetic but you can set the file name and location in your twig template

```
{% javascripts 
    'bundles/acmefoo/css/*'
    output='css/compiled/main.css' <--
    %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endjavascripts %}
```